# Install BeautifulSoup on python3.5, Mac , ImportError:No module named 'bs4'

Tags: macos, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I want to install BeautifulSoup, I use python3.5  on Mac
I have tried many methods:
I try to download `beautifulsoup4-4.4.1.tar.gz` from official website,and in terminal type:

> $ cd [my path]
>
> $ sudo python3.5 ./setup.py install

I also tried:

> $ sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4

and the terminal says:

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3.5.egg

So I think it is already installed,
but when In python3 I type (I use pycharm)

> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

It says

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Applications/PyCharm Edu.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
>       module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
>   ImportError: No module named 'bs4'

Did I install bs4 properly?
How can I import bs4 into python3?

Comment: So what does `import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)` (in PyCharm) tell you is your Python path? It looks as if you are using a different Python version in PyCharm.

Comment: Also, PyCharm can install packages for you in the currently picked Python version.

Comment: the sys.path is['/Applications/PyCharm Edu.app/Contents/helpers/pydev',
 '/Applications/PyCharm Edu.app/Contents/helpers/pydev',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/Users/jiaru2014/Desktop/Python_learning']

Comment: Curious. And that is in the exact same place that `import bs4` fails?

Comment: >>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm Edu.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: So it appears you have the `beautifulsoup4` metadata, but not the package. Use `pip3 install --force-reinstall beautifulsoup4` to force pip to clean up and re-install.

Comment: The terminal says:     Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3.5.egg
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.           And in pycharm it still have and Import Error:No module named 'bs4'

Comment: So use `pip3 install --force-reinstall --upgrade beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/beautifulsoup4/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoup4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for beautifulsoup4

Comment: Do you need to use a proxy to reach the network perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I'm in China, I always use VPN to reach the Internet.... And I have already solved the problem!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this porblem!

just as @Martjin Pieters said,PyCharm can install packages by Menu Operation：
PyCharm -> Preference -> Project -> Project interpreter
Check if you are using python3 and click "+" at the bottom (If you see BeatifulSoup in the frame, click "-" to uninstall it first) then you can install it properly

[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXLYt.png)